# Localization settings after login doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, dotnetnuke

I have dotnetnuke application and I made a custom login module. And everything works fine except loading user proffered locale. If user default language is set to German I want to change language from english to german after login. I write this code bellow but it works on my local instalation but not on the real server :(

```
string p = this.UserInfo.Profile.PreferredLocale;
               System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha, I get it :)

```
string lang = objUser.Profile.PreferredLocale;
                Response.Redirect(DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(this.TabId, true, this.PortalSettings, String.Empty, lang), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

DNN handles changing the locale for you; you shouldn't need to do this (and are probably running into conflicts with DNN when you do).

Go to the Languages page under the Admin menu, and make sure that all of your supported languages are enabled, and all of the settings match what you expect.

Comment: In admin languages I have all set as needed. In application header I have dropDownList that allows me to change languages and it works. When I use DNN Login module and login as user with prefered locale German it loads german language. But when I use my custom login module it doesn't change. It's wired because it works on my local installation of dnn :(

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I haven't worked with DNN so far, but if you just want to avoid it you might want to just save the chosen culture (i.e. the IETF-Tag) in a Session-Variable and create a Class inheriting `Page` which all your pages implement that overrides `InitializeCulture` and sets the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture`.